# to many redirects login security.yml

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I have got that code. But when I go in browser to app_dev.php/login
The browser say: that the page has made too many redirects

security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    user_db:
        entity: { class: DotfusionMerlinBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   login
            target: login
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

routing.yml

```
login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: DotfusionMerlinBundle:User:login }

login_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
```

Comment: Your login page is protected, see also http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-common-pitfalls

Comment: I have that:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
so, login form should not be protected,but something is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pop this under firewalls before the secured_area entry:

```
login_firewall:
    pattern: ^/login$
    anonymous: ~
```

That should fix your problem. Hope that helps.

Comment: from symfony4 document: "If you're using multiple firewalls and you authenticate against one firewall, you will not be authenticated against any other firewalls automatically. Different firewalls are like different security systems. " https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in an application that I had to do a deployment for and the error was as well in the security.yml file but at a different setting:

I had to change the line:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
```

to:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Because I did a deployment with https. (**Change http to https in the access control config**)